# Why can't I see JSON data on my screen using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I created two different labels and I want to display name and emails from JSON. I don't know why but it's not working. Any solution?

P.S. I am very new with Swift.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameJson: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailJson: UILabel!

    struct UserData: Decodable {
        var name: String
        var email: String
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let source = URL(string:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: source) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let JsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: data)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.nameJson.text = JsonData.name
                        self.emailJson.text = JsonData.email
                    }
                }
                catch {

                }
            }
        }.resume()        
    }
}
```

Comment: "is not working" isn't a very helpful description. Have you debugged your code or used some print statements? Is the data downloaded, is the json decoded, do you get any errors? Why are you not doing `print(error)` in the catch? Please make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: feel free to delete any property/struct that you don't need for now

Comment: it's a very important to have `print(error)` inside `catch` block it will guide you solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json data is an array so you must decode to an array by putting brackets around your JSONDecoder's `.decode([UserData].self` instead of just `.decode(UserData.self`. Here is how to decode and display the first name and email (though you should probably use a table view or collection view to display your list of data).

```
let source = URL(string:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: source) { (data, response, error) in

    if let data = data {
        do {
            let users = try JSONDecoder().decode([UserData].self, from: data)
            print(users)

            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.nameJson.text = users[0].name
                self.emailJson.text = users[0].email
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

I've also updated your UserData struct with commented lines for all data in your model. Uncomment if you want to access them.

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
//    var id: Int
    var name: String
//    var username: String
    var email: String
//    var address: addy
//    var phone: String
//    var website: String
//    var company: Dictionary<String, String>
//
//    struct addy: Decodable {
//        var street: String
//        var suite: String
//        var city: String
//        var zipcode: String
//        var geo: Dictionary<String, String>
//    }
}
```

Comment: nope, i did not put down vote. Thank u very much for explanation. It s clear now. Best!
thank u very much again ❤️

Comment: @HakanKurhan, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The root of your json is an array indicated by `[{---}]` not a dictionary indicated by `{---}` , so you should use `[UserData]` instead of `UserData`

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([UserData].self, from: data)
jsonData.forEach {
   print($0.name)
   print($0.email)
}
```

---

```
// MARK: - UserData
struct UserData: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, username, email: String
    let address: Address
    let phone, website: String
    let company: Company
}

// MARK: - Address
struct Address: Codable {
    let street, suite, city, zipcode: String
    let geo: Geo
}

// MARK: - Geo
struct Geo: Codable {
    let lat, lng: String
}

// MARK: - Company
struct Company: Codable {
    let name, catchPhrase, bs: String
}
```